# Restore terminal log mac printed output

Tags: macos, terminal, recovery, data-recovery, disaster-recovery

Is there a way to recovery the output of a terminal? My MacBook stopped working and restarted, now I lost the information of the screen of the terminal. I need to recovery it because I need to use the output printed data, is there a way?

This message is on the top of terminal:
[Restored contents truncated]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, to the best of my knowledge, there's no history of terminal output unless you were logging it (ex: by using a logging script).

Can you recreate the output by running the same commands again?

To see the commands you typed you can simply use `history`.

Answer (score 1):

for future reference:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3360245?start=0&tstart=0

someone said, "Take a look at the comand `script`

`man script`

...
 It logs everything printed to the terminal. I haven't ever tried it in OS X but it should do what you want."